# Dotted border doesn't appear right at either ends

Tags: css

Something which has been frustrating me is the CSS `border:dotted;` rule. I have been using this below:

```
border-bottom:#1C9AD5 dotted 2px;
```

If you take a look at [my example](http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/what-we-do/branding-print/), and look at the blue dotted line it goes a bit weird at either end (it looks as though there's two dots really close together).

I know I can easily get around this by using an image but that isn't the point!

Comment: Looks fine for me in Chrome 10. Can you show a screen shot? What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: What browser are you viewing this on?

Comment: What browser are you encountering this problem in? It all looks fine to me in the browsers I tested. (Oh, and it looks like you have a pretty talented lineup of employees there. Quite magical, I'd say :P)

Comment: Umm Chrome - 11.0.696.71 on a mac. @BraedenP haha!

Comment: Looks good in FF4 for a Mac, Chrome 10 for Mac, and Safari 4 for Mac.

Comment: Looks like it is only on certain zoom levels for Chrome.  I don't know how to zoom on a mac, but on Windows, you hold CTRL and roll your mouse wheel.

Comment: @briguy37 you should put that as an answer because that's exactly the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my earlier comment as a solution based on Jason's comment:

"Looks like it is only on certain zoom levels for Chrome.  I don't know how to zoom on a mac, but on Windows, you hold CTRL and roll your mouse wheel."

Comment: Yep, that's definitely it. Strange! And unfortunately, Rob, I don't think there's any way to fix it. That's something that will have to be ironed out in future Webkit releases. I'd just go for an image if you're worried about that happening.

Comment: I've zoomed in and out and still it's there. I don't think it has anything to do with the zoom.

Comment: @Rob Looks like you've already updated your site to have the underline as a picture, so I made a fiddle for testing (http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/JBjEm/).  For me, it only shows double at the ends on certain zoom levels, so don't know why you don't get the same.  To me, it looks like Chrome forces the underline to end on the corners, but only has a fixed size in screen pixels for the dots and spaces, and thus stretches them as needed.  I've made several divs in my fiddle to test this, each 1px bigger than the previous.  For me, at least one of them shows correctly at each zoom level.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Test 3 was the closest on mine but it doubles up at the start but not the end. It doesn't seem like it's just a Chrome thing as it does the same on Safari! Think we'll just have to put it down to a Mac thing!! P.s Yep gave up and just used images, sigh.